# calenldy prefill phone number field

Tags: javascript, calendly

I want to prefill phone number in calendly through url.
I can fill other information like name and email but phone number is not filled.

Here a1 fills the form below phone number. I tried filling with field name `phone_number` but no luck with that.

Need help

Answer (score 2):

If your event type's location is set to "Phone call" you can prefill the phone number input field by using the `location` url parameter.